# Colormaps with a colorscale AND one color for unwanted values

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I would like to plot a grid of 3 variables (same min, same max, same spacing) in 3D and I would like each point on the grid to have a specific color according to a function f which is a function of these 3 variables except for when the values of the function are superior to a specific threshold for which I assign another color.

The code below as what I have tried so far:

```py
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.colors
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import numpy as np
import math
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap, LinearSegmentedColormap

%matplotlib notebook

x = np.arange(0.001, 0.175, 0.01)
y = np.arange(0.001, 0.175, 0.01)
z = np.arange(0.001, 0.175, 0.01)

X, Y, Z = np.meshgrid(x, y, z)

def function(X,Y,Z):
   '''function of (X,Y,Z) going from 0 to high values'''
   return(f)

f=function(X,Y,Z)

#flatten the f array (I think there is a function to flatten an array but I have seen it to late)
fflat=[]
for l in f:
    for p in l:
        for t in p:
            fflat.append(t) 

#masking high values with the highest interesting value: maxV              
mfflat = ma.masked_greater(fflat, maxV)
mfflat = mfflat.filled(maxV)

#normalizing values and mapping to veridis cmap:
cmap = matplotlib.cm.get_cmap('viridis')
norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=min(mfflat), vmax=maxV) #(vmax=maxV=max(mfflat))
colors = [cmap(norm(value)) for value in mfflat]

#plot
ax.scatter(X, Y, Z, color=colors, s=10, alpha=1)
cax, _ = matplotlib.colorbar.make_axes(ax)
cbar = matplotlib.colorbar.ColorbarBase(cax, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
```

The problem is that now all the "unwanted high values", i.e. values > maxV have the same colors as my "maximal wanted values", i.e. maxV ...

I would like all my "unwanted values" outside of my veridis colorscale and giving them another unique color.

Thanks for your help !
Cheers

Comment: colormaps have an `over` attribute; you can set the color via `cmap.set_over(..)`. For this you would need to use the scatter's `c` argument and specify your colormap to be used with scatter.

Comment: Indeed, it is helpful to read the documentation sometimes ...

I have found a solution in the meantime however: I have removed the masks and created my color list as follow:

colors=[]
for value in fflat:
    if minV <= value <= maxV:
        colors.append(cmap(norm(value)))
    else:
        colors.append((255/258,255/258,255/258,1))

But indeed, just by adding cmap.set_over and cmap.set_under you get the same result more easily !
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to ImportanceOfBeingErnest for the answer, I just had to use: **cmap.set_over**, here is the corrected code:

```
x = np.arange(0.001, 0.175, 0.01)
y = np.arange(0.001, 0.175, 0.01)
z = np.arange(0.001, 0.175, 0.01)

X, Y, Z = np.meshgrid(x, y, z)

def function(X,Y,Z):
   '''function of (X,Y,Z) going from 0 to high values'''
   return(f)

f=function(X,Y,Z)

#flatten the f array (I think there is a function to flatten an array but I have seen it to late)
fflat=[]
for l in f:
    for p in l:
        for t in p:
            fflat.append(t) 

cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('viridis')
cmap.set_over(color=(0,0,0), alpha=0.5)
norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=minV, vmax=maxV)
colors = [cmap(norm(value)) for value in fflat]

#plot
ax.scatter(X, Y, Z, color=colors, s=10, alpha=1)
cax, _ = matplotlib.colorbar.make_axes(ax)
cbar = matplotlib.colorbar.ColorbarBase(cax, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
```

In the meantime I have found a workaround by creating the "colors" list selectively which is of course not as clean as using cmap.set_over:

```
colors=[]
for value in fflat:
    if minV <= value <= maxV:
        colors.append(cmap(norm(value)))
    else:
        colors.append((255/258,255/258,255/258,0))
```